# Is it possible to persist cookies between cross domain requests?

Tags: rest

I am trying to do a SSO to a different domain which uses REST API to give us some data and a starting Point URL back and then we need to launch that starting Point URL.
I am unable to persist the cookies as soon as I launch the URL. I am wondering if it is even possible to do that?
All of our code runs in ASP.net environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cookies don't go away; but a browser will **only** send cookies for the originating domain when making a page request. The cookies will once again "appear" after/if the SSO redirects back to the page on the domain for which the cookies have been set.

There are also third-party cookies, but those are for when the page *makes* a resource request to a different domain, not when loading a new page from a different domain. These can generally be blocked independently of first-party cookies.